# Does {1em} mean {1em plus0pt minus0pt}?

Tags: spacing, lengths

Is `plus0pt` and `minus0pt` automatically added if I write, e.g.,

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1em}
\setlength{\jot}{0pt}
\setlength{\parsep}{0pt}
...
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only if TeX expects a glue. Lengths with `skip` in the name are always glues (unless the programmer is a bit crazy). But there are some other length "variables". For example `\hsize` accepts a ⟨dimen⟩, for example `\hsize 4in`. There the plus and minus do not apply. Charles has shown the example of `\hbox` that accepts a ⟨dimen⟩ as well.

See chapter 24 of the TeXbook for a complete definition.

Answer (score 4):

Semantically, yes, but not syntactically: `\hbox to 10pt` doesn't *expand* to `\hbox to 10pt plus 0pt minus 0pt`.

Comment: Well, `\hbox` doesn't expand at all. But note that you can use a skip register to specify a dimension. The `plus` and `minus` parts are simply ignored: `\skip0 2cm plus 5cm minus 2cm
\hbox to\skip0{This works, but is overfull.}'

Comment: @TH.: Right, and good point about casting skips to dimens.  I could make this answer more precise, but Patrick's answer covers the ground.  I'd have deleted it for being redundant, but his answer refers to this one.